# (.text.write_float+0xf7d): undefined reference to `quadmath_snprintf'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, g++

What should I fix in the Makefile?

```
jalal@klein:~/computer_vision/mmglm_neuroimage_private-master/lib/c++/src$ make
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -static mmglm_spd_multithread.cpp -o ../bin/mmglm_spd_par -fopenmp -O3 -llapack -lblas -lpthread -lgfortran  -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -I ../lib/armadillo-3.930.2/include/
mmglm_spd_multithread.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
mmglm_spd_multithread.cpp:117:10: warning: unused variable ‘length’ [-Wunused-variable]
   size_t length=0;//initializing length as a counter
          ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgomp.a(target.o): In function `gomp_target_init':
(.text+0xba): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a(write.o): In function `write_float':
(.text.write_float+0xb2): undefined reference to `signbitq'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a(write.o): In function `write_float':
(.text.write_float+0xbf): undefined reference to `finiteq'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a(write.o): In function `write_float':
(.text.write_float+0x133): undefined reference to `quadmath_snprintf'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a(write.o): In function `write_float':
(.text.write_float+0x254): undefined reference to `finiteq'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a(write.o): In function `write_float':
(.text.write_float+0xaff): undefined reference to `isnanq'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a(write.o): In function `write_float':
(.text.write_float+0xb83): undefined reference to `quadmath_snprintf'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a(write.o): In function `write_float':
(.text.write_float+0xf7d): undefined reference to `quadmath_snprintf'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a(write.o): In function `write_float':
(.text.write_float+0x10d8): undefined reference to `quadmath_snprintf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'multithread' failed
make: *** [multithread] Error 1
```

I have:
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.

```
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)
```

and

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Here's the related lines from `Makefile`:

```
CC= g++
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -static
#-static
#INC_PATH=  -I ../lib/armadillo-7.100.3/include/
INC_PATH=  -I ../lib/armadillo-3.930.2/include/
LIB_PATH=  -llapack -lblas -lpthread -lgfortran  -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
#LIB_PATH= -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER 
#lrefblas
all: multithread mmglm show_arma_mx armabin2asciifull armabinequaltotxt
multithread_fast:
        $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) mmglm_spd_multithread_fast.cpp -o ../bin/mmglm_spd_par_fast -fopenmp -O3 $(LIB_PATH) $(INC_PATH)
multithread:
        $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) mmglm_spd_multithread.cpp -o ../bin/mmglm_spd_par -fopenmp -O3 $(LIB_PATH) $(INC_PATH)
```

I even tried having -lquadmath flag but got the same error:

```
multithread:
        $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) mmglm_spd_multithread.cpp -o ../bin/mmglm_spd_par -fopenmp -lquadmath -O3 $(LIB_PATH) $(INC_PATH)
```

I also have the following packages installed:

```
 2043  sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev 
 2044  sudo apt-get install liblapacke
 2045  sudo apt-get install liblapacke-dev
 2046  sudo apt-get install libblas-dev 
 2048  sudo apt-get install gfortran
 2049  sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev 
 2050  sudo apt-get install liblapack3
 2052  sudo apt-get install libarmadillo-dev
 2056  sudo apt-get install libarmadillo6
 2057  sudo apt-get install libarmadillo6-dbgsym
 2071  sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
 2077  sudo apt-get install libboost-system-dev
 2080  sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev
```

Comment: Did you read the warning?

Comment: I see in answers they say do this `extern "C" {
#include "quadmath.h"
}` but I am not sure where and how! https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-06/msg00148.html

Comment: `-lm`? ________

Comment: @cjhanks if you mean `  $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) mmglm_spd_multithread.cpp -o ../bin/mmglm_spd_par -fopenmp -lm -O3 $(LIB_PATH) $(INC_PATH)` no it didn't help!

Comment: Since its libgfortran that needs these symbols, you need to add `-lquadmath` *after* `-lgfortran`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding `-lquadmath` at the end of this line:

```
LIB_PATH=  -llapack -lblas -lpthread -lgfortran  -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lquadmath
```